use of undeclared crate or module `alloc` when upgrade to `v1.13.0`
I got this error below when running psvm -v 1.13.0
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `alloc`
      --> /Users/chungquantin/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/frame-benchmarking-35.0.0/src/v1.rs:1738:2
       |
  1738 | /     sp_runtime::format_runtime_string!(
  1739 | |         "\n* Pallet: {}\n\
  1740 | |         * Benchmark: {}\n\
  1741 | |         * Components: {:?}\n\
  ...    |
  1750 | |         error_message,
  1751 | |     )
       | |_____^ use of undeclared crate or module `alloc`
       |
       = note: this error originates in the macro `sp_runtime::format_runtime_string` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)


It is an error in the macro hygiene of the format_runtime_string! macro. The bug will be fixed by the following PR: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/5632

I would suggest using Zepter (https://github.com/ggwpez/zepter) to verify that all the features are propagated correctly.

Have tried but it does not solve the issue. Did you get this? I got this right away after running pvm -v 1.13.0

we have the same problem. and zepter can't resolve it. double checked feature propagation manually. no success
